# Using PowerShell how to replace and save a value in a json file having comments

Tags: json, .net, regex, powershell, app-config

I have a Json file having multiple comments and I want to replace a value in it.

I tried the below and it gives me a json file without comments. But I don't understand how to change the value and save it back with comments. Is this even possible because we are replacing all the comments with empty lines?

```
$json = Get-Content $jsonfile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$configfile = $json -replace '(?m)(?<=^([^"]|"[^"]*")*)//.*' -replace '(?ms)/\*.*?\*/'
```

My config.json is as below and I want to change the value of "version" to 10 through a powershell script and then save it back with the comments intact.

```html
    {
        "FramewokSettings": {
            "Name": "VX",
            "Version": "8",  // The value here is not constant. It can be something like v1.4.56.456 also
            "GitVersion": "v5",
            "DatabaseVersion": "7",
            // Doing xyz 
            "CounterVersion": "2"
            // Doing ABC. 
            // Start
         }
}
```

Comment: `(Get-Content $jsonfile) -replace '(?<=^\s*"Version"\s*:\s*")[^"]*(?="\s*$)', '10' | Set-Content $jsonfile`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @WiktorStribiżew. I am a newbee to regex and I tried the above and get Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

Comment: @kat, before running Wiktor's code you first need to set `$jsonfile = .\path\to\your\file`.

Comment: You can preserve comments starting with PowerShell version 6. Are you using version 6 or greater?

Comment: I used this command `(Get-Content test.txt) -replace '(?<=^\s*"Version"\s*:\s*")[^"]*(?="\s*$)', '10' | Set-Content test.txt` and then tried to verify using `Get-Content test.txt` if the new value has set. But I still see th eold value.

Comment: @GregoryShields our agents doesn't have a powershell version above 6.

Comment: @GregoryShields, while `ConvertFrom-Json` _tolerates_ comments  in PowerShell (Core) v6+, it doesn't _preserve_ them.

Comment: I see, my suggestion did not work due to the fact there is a comma and a comment after `"`, the `(?="\s*$)` should  be either `(?=")` or removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(Get-Content test.txt) -replace '^(\s*"Version"\s*:\s*")[^"]*', '${1}10' | Set-Content test.txt
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/k1pKiT/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to $1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "Version"                '"Version"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of $1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: If I have to replace the new value as a variable ($somenumber instead of the constant 10) How do I do that? I tried replacing 10 with `$somenumber` and it replaces with `$somenumber` instead of the value assigned to the variable `somenumber.

Comment: @kat There are mutiple ways. ``'${1}' + $somenumber`` is IMHO the simplest. ``"`${1}$somenumber"`` is also a way.